# Activate Android device on IPv6-only network

Tags: ipv6, activation

- Is it possible to activate an Android phone on a network with IPv6-only access to the Internet?
- Does Google support all their services over IPv6?
- Has anyone tried it?

I'm going to need to activate an Android device on an IPv6-only network in the near future. Any help regarding this appreciated.

Comment: The only way you can get IPv6 is to roll your own kernel **but** you are on your own since 1) no device mentioned and 2) no Android version mentioned so we cannot tell from there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Google services are [accessible via IPv6, since June 6, 2012](https://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1299266).

And yes, I've tried it myself. My own Android is on IPv6.

Comment: IPv6 unequal to IPv6-only. So are you sure that you did not have IPv4 access (along side IPv6) when you activated your device?

Comment: Oh, and just FYI, the page you linked to doesn't mention anywhere that *all* Google services are available over IPv6. It just said it was enabled, but no mentions of it was full or partial.

Comment: Yes, it is fully enabled and you can access Google from an IPv6-only network. Perhaps English is not your native language?